Add Week Number to line chart while keeping Continuous X-axis
I have a date hierarchy and I want to include my Week Number column in my line chart. Adding in the fields from my date hierarchy keeps my line chart's x-axis continuous. As soon as I add my week number, it becomes categorical (a slider appears on the line chart). How would I go about keeping my line chart's x-axis continuous when I include Week Number?
My Week Number column already comes in with the input data and the logic is ISOWEEKNUM on the input file. It has a Numerical datatype.
First image: No week number included yet. Has continuous x-axis (also has an option to change to categorical)
Second image: Week number included. Has categorical x-axis (option to change between categorical and continuous disappears)
I tried creating a custom date hierarchy with the same fields as the premade date hierarchy + my Week Number column. I get the same issue where the line chart's x-axis changes to categorical type.
